# duplicate content in https without certificate? and google tries HTTPS anyway?

Tags: google, https, google-adsense, security-certificate, http

I understand that for an HTTPS page to work properly, a valid certificate is required.

On my web server, we primarily use HTTP but we have HTTPS available to clients that may need it. I then tried a website designed for HTTP using HTTPS and as expected I receive a message about no valid certificate which is normal, but when I approve of it, I'm sent to the default page from the document root of the servers IP address rather than the virtual host I accessed.

My question is Am I exempt from filtering out duplicate content with HTTPS for having no valid certificate installed?

And my second question is, does Google (particularly Google Adsense) scan sites for HTTPS versions to see if they produce valid pages (with http status 200) before deciding to pay publishers more pennies?